# react-native issue with displaying 3d model on iOS - expo.three, react-three-fiber

Tags: react-native, 3d, expo, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to display 3d model in react-native iOS, but with no luck yet. I tried two libraries: `expo-three`, `react-fiber-three`.
Both working great on Android - no issues here, but when I'm trying to run it on iOS I'm just getting empty screen - 3d model hasn't being loaded.

By any chance does anybody worked lately with this libraries and have a luck with iOS setup? I would appreciate any information.